# How to stop Pkg.xxx() command in Julia?

Tags: julia

When I run `Pkg.update()`, `Pkg.status()`, sometimes, Julia hangs there. Is there a way to stop the Pkg-related command? I tried `C-c, C-c, C-d, C-q`, none of them works.

Is there a way to stop those command?

Comment: ctrl-C works on UNIXes. I assume from your other questions that you're on Windows?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Yes. I'm on Windows 7. I have to kill the process using Windows Task Manager, and start again. I wish I could cancel these package related commands. By the way, it takes me hours to run `Pkg.update()`, stops at `julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...` Can I do something to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

`Pkg.xxx()` starts a number of detached tasks which are not killed even when the `Pkg` command is interrupted using `Ctrl-C`.  To kill these tasks, use `interrupt(workers())`.

It looks like the behaviour of `Ctrl-C` might be improved in a future version of Julia with [RFC14032](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/14032).